# Async/Await in WCF Operation

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm currently making our WCF services asynchronous, this WCF service will be called from PHP on the client side and I know that there is a way to call services from PHP asynchronously, but is it good practice to have the following code in my WCF project?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<List<string>> GetEmployeeUsernames();
}

public class Employee : IEmployeeService
{
    public async Task<List<string>> GetEmployeeUsernames()
    {
        // some logic here...
        using (WebResponse response = await wr.GetResponseAsync())
        {
             // some logic here...
        }
    }
}
```

I was reading about task-based implementation of WCF but when I removed/changed all our existing methods in our WCF project with async methods Visual Studio did not allow it when I tried to run and debug.

Comment: What was the error that prevented you from running it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot what the error was. But it should've worked right? theoretically, yes?

Comment: Yeah… look’s good at first glance, but that say’s nothing. Could you please try to run it again and post the error?

Comment: I will try to recreate the error, I've made a lot of changes already with the code.